# access mounted data in jupyter notebook on amazon ec2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook using data and notebooks that are mounted on an EBS volume on my ec2 instance.  My ec2 instance uses ubuntu.  My directory structure looks like the following:

/

---|mountedData

---|localData

I used the instructions provided here [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-and-using-jupyter-notebooks-on-aws-61a9648db6c5) to set up the notebook.  When I invoke the jupyter notebook command from **/** or from **/localData** it is successful. However, I can't navigate to the **/mountedData** directory (it doesn't even show up on the browser's file navigation screen).  If I launch the jupyter notebook from within **/mountedData** I get an error in the browser

```
Server error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1699, in _execute result = await result File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper yielded = next(result) File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content, File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 431, in get model = self._dir_model(path, content=content) File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 313, in _dir_model for name in os.listdir(os_dir): PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/snapd/void'`
```

All directories are owned by root and root is the usergroup.  I even tried chmod 777'ing the **/mountedData** but that didn't help.  I also tried symlinking the mounted data within **/localData** as I saw suggested online but that produces a 404 not found error when I try to click on the symlink. Unfortunately ditching the mounted data is not an option as I am working with TBs of data that I need to mount and attach to ec2 instances.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by uninstalling the version of jupyter I had installed via snap, then reinstalling jupyter via anaconda.  So the moral of the story is to use anaconda to install python packages!

Comment: Thank you for answering your question :)

Comment: I too received the same error message despite having set all permissions to 0777 for the directories. Does this mean the snap install of Jupyter Notebook simply does not work?